# cakephp usermin password not saving

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to edit a company and update the password which is in the umusers table. If I use save it updates the company but not the password in the umusers table. If I use saveAll it creates a new user in the umusers table.

Here is my setup

Company Model I have:

```
    public $hasOne = 'Umuser';
```

Company Controller

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->Company->id = $id;
    if (!$this->Company->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid company'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        if ($this->Company->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The company has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The company could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data = $this->Company->read(null, $id);
    }

}
```

var_dump of the $this->request->data:

```
array(2) { ["Company"]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> string(3) "157" ["member_number"]=> string(6) "234234" ["name"]=> string(5) "keith" ["address1"]=> string(5) "keith" ["address2"]=> string(5) "keith" ["county"]=> string(5) "keith" ["limited"]=> string(1) "0" ["tax_number"]=> string(5) "keith" ["contact_name"]=> string(5) "keith" ["phone"]=> string(5) "keith" ["email"]=> string(15) "keith@keith.com" ["payment_start"]=> array(3) { ["month"]=> string(2) "02" ["day"]=> string(2) "01" ["year"]=> string(4) "2013" } } ["Umuser"]=> array(1) { ["password"]=> string(6) "keith1" } }
```

I know at the moment I am not hashing the password or unsetting it if it is left blank. What am I missing, some relationship with the id's perhaps?

Comment: What's happening inside of `save()`? Also, what field type is password in the db?

Comment: that is the var_dump data I have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    In this you need to get the "umuser id" & specify the id value as below..
     {
        ["Company"]=> {
            ["id"]=> "157" 
             ......
        }
        ["Umuser"] => {
            ["id"]=> "some value"
            ["password"]=> "keith1"
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have passed id as a hidden field in the edit form.

```
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
```